# Inserting 1 or multiple rows into a table from the results of a select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing a stored procedure to insert single or multiple rows from a table to the same table again with some modifications.

It is not clear how many rows will be inserted, it can be only one or 10. I need to insert them all with some fields changed.

I looked at other questions but couldn't find anything help with my unclear number of rows problem.

Can I just take the results into a temporary table and do my modifications, then insert them to the table again? Would it work on this 1 or n number of rows?

EDIT: 
Example
There are 6 rows with same idenfitifier. (Actual table contains 36 columns, I'm using these 5 as an example)

```
+-----+--------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
| Id  | NctsId | BeyanIndex |       CancelDate        |   LRN    |
+-----+--------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 263 |     97 | NULL       | NULL                    | NULL     |
| 264 |     97 | NULL       | 2015-11-02 12:38:15.953 | MULTI    |
| 265 |     97 | 0          | NULL                    | NULL     |
| 266 |     97 | 1          | NULL                    | NULL     |
| 267 |     97 | 0          | 2015-11-02 12:38:15.953 | test1313 |
| 268 |     97 | 1          | 2015-11-02 12:34:32.060 | test1414 |
+-----+--------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

I need to take the ones with the ID's 264,267 and 268. 
These Id's are the result of a select of course, they are based on some criteria.

Then I need to insert them again into same table with some modifications on the ones with the ID's 267 and 268.

So far only a temp table and a @@rowcount feels like right in handling this to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the rows to be processed with a WHERE clause and create the modified versions in a SELECT query, then you can use INSERT...SELECT, which will do 0 or more rows depending on how many meet the WHERE specification.

```
INSERT tbl (col1, ...)
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN something THEN modified-column-expression 
      WHEN something-else ...
    END col1
  , ...
  FROM tbl
  WHERE id in (list-of-affected-ids)
```

This seems to be what you need, but you are suggesting not...what have I missed?